# System memory exception on for loop

Tags: c#

I have the following code below:

```
List<long> numbers = new List<long>();

for (long i = 1; i <= 300000000; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(i);
}
```

What I wanted to do is to populate the list from 1-300 million. But when it hit the 67108865, it throws an exception on line 4: `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

I tried using `ulong` but still no luck.

I believe the maximum range for `long` data type is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 but why am I having an error here?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Thanks for all the answers. It helped my realized that my design is not good. I ended up changing my code design.

Comment: If this is a 32-bit app, you probably hit the limit for your available address space

Comment: Thanks but I still got an error but now on the 134217729. I used the 64-bit settings.

Comment: it might be the List<> capacity try LinkedList<> instead

Comment: Gerald what are you doing that you require that many object in memory at once? You may need to use a different design strategy, like partitioning the data in to smaller chunks or using a database instead of storing the entire list in memory.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am solving one of the problems in the Project Euler. I agree with you because I tried partitioning the list, using x64-bit app but my computer gave up because my RAM is not sufficient (4GB only).

Comment: The point of Project Euler is to give you problems that are hard to solve directly and usually require critical thinking because the obvious brute force method wont work (do to thinks like memory constraints, for your problem). If it takes more than 30 seconds for your computer to come up with a answer once you enter the last input there is likely a better way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is not that your number are to large, but your list is...
Lets calculate it's size:

```
300,000,000 * 64 bits (size of long) = 19,200,000,000 bits
19,200,000,000 /8 (size of byte) = 2,400,000,000
2,400,000,000 / 2^10 = 2,343,750 KB
2,343,750 / 2^10 = 2,288~ MB
2,288/ 2^10 = 2.235~ GB
```

You wanted a list of about 2.35 GB.
The current CLR limitation is 2 GB (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906891/what-is-the-max-limit-of-data-into-liststring-in-c) SO thread)

If you need a list with size of `300,000,000`, split it into 2 lists (either in place or using a wrapping object that will handle managing the lists).

Comment: I ended up splitting it into 3 lists but my machine ended up not responding because of too much memory being consumed up. Thanks for the answer btw!

Answer (score 1):

First note `System.OutOfMemoryException` is not thrown when limit is reached for a variable,
Secondly, it is thrown because there is not enough memory available to continue the execution of a program.
Sadly you can not configure, .the NET runtime makes all the decisions about heap size and memory.
Either switch to 64-bit machine.

For info, on 32 bit machine you can increase the memory by using  /3GB boot switch option in Boot.ini

**EDIT** While searching I found in [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) under **Remarks** section

> By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2 gigabytes (GB). In a 64-bit environment, you can avoid the size restriction by setting the enabled attribute of the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` configuration element to `true` in the run-time environment. However, the array will still be limited to a total of 4 billion elements, and to a maximum index of 0X7FEFFFFF in any given dimension (0X7FFFFFC7 for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures).

A `List<long>` is backed by an `long[]`. You will fail as soon as the backing array cannot be allocated, during the reallocation, there has to be enough total memory for both the old and the new arrays.

But, if you want a collection with more than 2<sup>31</sup> elements, you have to write your own implementation by using multiple arrays or `List`, and managing them.

Comment: Is there any way to configure my machine to allocate enough memory on my application to run?

Comment: @Gerald There is no way to do so because it is a CLR limitation, not a "application setting"

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers are not too large; your list is too long. It is using all the available memory.

Reduce `300000000` to `3000000`, and it will (probably) work fine.

Comment: Yes, it will work fine with `3000000` but what I need is `300000000` as part of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It should ideally hold number of elements that you are telling.

But, as per current `CLR` implementation each object can have max `2 GB` size. As you are storing long values (size 8 bytes), then while populating the `List`, it is somewhere trying to exceed the 2GB limit. That's why you are getting `System.OutOfMemoryException`