# Reasonable size of List<ReferenceType> to have in memory

Tags: c#, list, memory, size, buffer

I know that there are limitations on the size of a List you can have in C# (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906891/what-is-the-max-limit-of-data-into-liststring-in-c)).

Assuming that my hardware permits it, would it be bad if I just let my List grow in-memory and use it from there, obviously as long as it doesn't exceed its capacity? I feel a bit naughty doing this. I expect my machine to be a couple of gigs in RAM.

If not, what would be a reasonable size to limit my List and then subsequently push to a database? My use-case will include asynchronously (and thread-safely) appending reference types to the list, as well as querying it (using Linq) for a set of the data based on their properties (eg time-based). The list will essentially be a time-series (ie time-stamped objects of data). I want to be able to do streaming analytics on the data (eg moving average), as well as time-based lookups, that may return the entire list.

Let's assume my list will be holding, at its largest, class objects (ie reference types), of around 3-5 million.

**UPDATE:**

As a reference, I have previously written the objects that are being appended to the list as JSONs to a text file (1 JSON per line). The size of the .txt file for 8,658 items is only 1,570KB. Extrapolating that to 5m objects comes close to 1GB.

Comment: A half million item sized list may be acceptable on a machine with 16gb ram, and completely unusable on a system with 512mb ram.  What are your use cases?

Comment: aha, I would be expecting an upper bound of 5 million objects

Comment: Ignoring the capabilities of a list (which I believe can support an item count that size), suppose each object (and graph) you're referencing is a paltry 512 bytes, that's already 2.4gb if you have 5 million.  If your objects are very complex (kilobytes or more) then your system may be swapping like crazy, or you could get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: I've just updated my question to make your comment more relevant :)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to accomplish with your large list?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I've eddited the middle paragraph to hopefully answer ur question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no limitations of size of `List` in .NET (besides the hard limits described in the link you provided). Apart from that the list will grow in memory until memory runs out and `OutOfMemoryException` is thrown. This is more probable than reaching hard coded limits.

Not removing objects from a collection is one of the causes of memory leak in C# code. Especially when the collection is static which ensures it will live until AppDomain is unloaded.

I would advise you to keep track of objects and remove them as soon as you don't need them.

Comment: In a 32 bit application you'll almost always run out of (unfragmented) memory before you hit the hard caps for a list's size.  In a 64 bit application the reverse is true, it's almost impossible to run out of unfragmented virtual memory before you hit the limit of a single object.