# How to create List<T> that can handle at least ulong number of items in c#?

Tags: c#, list

I want to create a list, that will handle A LOT (number of items will be stored in `ulong`) of items inside. I know, its a bit too much (int is sufficient for this task), but I was just wondering is this possible. Mainly: normal List can take as argument for `operator []` only int. I suppose its a limit of Lists. How to make larger Lists? Is there any other class, or would I have to work with `List<List<byte>>`?

Comment: The term 'a lot' is a bit broad. Is there any change to elaborate this with real values?

Comment: It will be a bit more than `UInt32` (`uint`) (4,000,000,000+) can handle.

Comment: If your list is really that long, you should probably use a file or a database. Putting that thing in memory is not going to end well.

Comment: I was just asking how to do such list. I know, that somewhere arond 4,000,000 objects stored would be fatal, but is there a way to create list that would handle such big numbers? (Btw. I cannot create a file/database. I will just wisely delete unused data from the list)

Comment: You cannot put for indexer another type except `int`.

Comment: your list will have more then `2147483647` items? if each item will ocupy only 24 bytes (minimal object size for Microsoft .NET CLR v4 on x64) this will be about 48GB of memory. Is this is not enough?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the max limit of data into list<string> in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906891/what-is-the-max-limit-of-data-into-liststring-in-c)

Comment: You can use indexers overload to add your type of indexer.

Comment: I suppose you could write your own class that uses a 2D array as a backing store. The array could theoretically store `int32` x `int32` items. Another option is to use a MemoryStream for storage and use Seek() to index into it.

Comment: @JohnWu I thought about it, but haven't anyone done this yet? I suppose it's going to be my task for today :)

Comment: @MartinVerjans it is not a duplicate for that. I was wondering how to do larger list, not what is the biggest possible size.

Comment: Either way storing that sort of data in the LOB is going to create problems one way or another sooner or later especially if you are letting this auto expand

Comment: Am I the only one who haven't got more than 48Gb of RAM to store such huge lists?

Comment: @vasily.sib what about list of bytes? It would not require  24B for one object will it? `List<List<byte>>`

Comment: @SkillGG, sure not (as `List<T>` is holding items in `T[]` internally, so `List<byte>` is actually a `byte[]`), 24B is a minimal **object** size. But for 4,000,000,000+ `byte` items this list will be still 4+Gb of RAM.

Comment: @SkillGG, also, as you working with this huge amount of data, your program can't run on `x86` so don't forget to switch your target from `AnyCPU` to `x64` in your Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a `Dictionary<ulong, T>`.

As long as the size of your Dictionary doesn't exceed the maximum authorized size, you will be fine.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was thinking about. I knew, that there has to be a way. That I don't have to do any `List<List<T>>` shenanigans or (worse) make own class for it.